# UIAnimation non-linear effects

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, user-interface

So I want to do a UI animation where a view gradually fades out. Right now I have something like this

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0f
    animations:^{
        myView.alpha = 0.0f;
    }
 ];
```

So right now over the course of those 2 seconds, the view will linearly gradually fade out. However I want to make it so that the fade out is non-linear. For instance, I want it to start fading out slowly and then fade more quickly over time.

How would I do this?

Comment: I believe that the default timing curve is actually "ease in, ease out" instead of "linear". You should be seeing that the start and end are slower than the middle of the animation

Answer (score 2):

Use one of the longer forms of animateWithDuration methods that take an options parameter, like `animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:`.

One of the options you can supply is a timing curve like UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut.

Your choices are

```
 UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut            = 0 << 16,
 UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn               = 1 << 16,
 UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut              = 2 << 16,
 UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear               = 3 << 16,
```

If you use CAAnimation instead of UIView animation, you can also create your own custom timing function using the control points of a bezier curve that describes the desired timing function. However, CAAnimation is more complex to use and less well documented.

Comment: I actually find Core Animation quite well documented, for example the [Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/CoreAnimationBasics/CoreAnimationBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH2-SW3) has a lot of good information in it (perhaps that because it's quite long as well). It's just more complex :D

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist, the docs are certainly better, and more complete, than they used to be.

Answer (score 0):

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
    myView.alpha = 0.0f;
} completion:nil];
```

Or pick your favorite time curve instead of `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut`

Answer (score 0):

You must be needing about "ease in" timing curve in which the animation starts slowly and ends as linear. Try the below code,

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
    myView.alpha = 0.0f;
} completion:nil];
```

Please do let me know, if it solves your problem.